# Changing value of element in array c++ and sizeof operator

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have the following array: `int arr[] = { 3,5,5,1,5 };` and I want to change the value of all the elements to `998`. How I do this is that I call two functions, one without the `size`, and one with size.

I know `size` can be determined by `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`, but this does not work in one of my functions.

In the first function, I don't pass in the size, and C++ calculates it.

```
change_array(arr, 998); // expect arr to become {998, 998, 998, 998, 998}
cout << " arr[2] = " << arr[2] << endl;
```

calls:

```
void change_array(int arr [],int new_value)
{
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); //I ran in debugger, but this doesn't work
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {

        arr[i] = new_value;

    }
}
```

but this prints `arr[2] = 5`.

When I pass in the size, like this:

```
change_array_size(arr, 5, 998);
cout << " arr[2] = " << arr[2] << endl;
```

then that calls:

```
void change_array_size(int arr[], int size, int new_value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        arr[i] = new_value;

    }
}
```

and in this one it actually changes the value: `arr[2] = 998`.

Why? The `sizeof` operator didn't seem to work in this case?

Comment: anything other than C C++ java?

Comment: ... Why the Java tag!?

Comment: Java is not needed , it's just C++

Comment: I took it out I added by accident cause it was in suggested.

Comment: then remove it. you have an [edit] button

Comment: I did remove it

Comment: So while debugging, what did `sizeof(arr)` show you?

Comment: it doesn't work in the function because the automatic sized array decays to an unknown size array/

Comment: This use of sizeof does not work for array parameters.  Might be better off using std::vector or std::array